# Template function parameter with const

Tags: c++, data-structures

I know reference is not like point. reference is not an object. so there is no const  reference.

```
const int ci = 1024;
const int &rl = ci;
```

we can't write `int const &rl = ...` But today ,I am learn a binary tree source code:

```
template <typename T> //take e as the node insert the left child of the tree.
BinNodePosi(T) BinNode<T>::insertAsLC(T const & e) {  return lChild = new BinNode(e, this);  }
```

I am confused with its parameter: **T const & e** .  why not **const T& e**?   I think the latter is right..  Maybe my question is too simple to post here. Unlike mathematics ,there are two side for Research level and study level respectively : MathOverFlow and math.stackexchange .. I can't find the junior site for stackoverflow.. So I post it here. Please forgive me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` applies to the thing immediately to its *left*, unless it is the first item in the type specifier sequence, in which case it applies to the next item.

So, `T const & e` is exactly equivalent to `const T & e`. The illegal case you seem to be thinking of is `T & const e`. Likewise, an immutable pointer to a mutable object would be declared `T * const e`.

Personally, I avoid putting `const` first because it is a special case of the grammar.